# How to get First Sunday/Second Sunday/Third Sunday/Forth Sunday (Or any Day) in a month after the mentioned date

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a query in sql where i can get first, second, third, forth any day (Sunday/Monday/Tuesday etc.) after passing a date.For Example -:

- Today is 2023-06-22
- I said i need **Second Wednesday**, so second wednesday after my current date will be on [2023-07-05]
- Similar way if i need to get first/second/third/fourth any day of week after my current date.

I tried to write sql query but its working only in case if i am passing Start date of month.

```html
DECLARE @FirstDateOfMonth datetime, -- First of the month of interest (no time part)
@WeekNumberOfMonth tinyint, -- Which of them - 1st, 2nd, etc.
@DayOfWeek tinyint -- Day of week we want
declare @result datetime
set @result = @FirstDateOfMonth + 7*(@WeekNumberOfMonth-1)
SELECT @result + (7 + @DayOfWeek - datepart(weekday,@result))%7
```

Anyone could help me out to write sql query with above requirement.

Comment: Do you mean specific *week days* after the current date? That's not `first, second or last day`. The easy way is to use a calendar table and get the first weekday you want after the current date. This can actually take advantage of indexes, on date and weekday fields while an expression can't. Eg `select top 1 Date,WeekDay from Calendar where Date>GETDATE() and WeekDay='Saturday' ORDER BY Date`

Comment: A Calendar table is a table containing dates for eg 20 years in the future along with year, month, quarter, weekday, semester, any field that may be useful in reporting. There are many scripts that generate calendar tables, eg [this one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). They're usually heavily indexed, making it *very* easy to create quarterly, month over month or year-to-date reports

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edit my question and tried to explain with an example, could you  please check once.

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` to number the Wednesdays and get the second one. Or you can get the first one after `date + 7*(n-1)`. Using `ROW_NUMBER()` requires writing a subquery or CTE because you can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Create a tally table with enough values to reach your target date and generate a record-set of dates. Select the max value where the datepart matches your criteria.

```
declare @date      date;
declare @number    tinyint;
declare @dayofweek tinyint;

declare @daysout int = 7 * @number;

with tally as (
   select top(@daysout)
          row_number() over (order by t1.column_id) N
     from sys.columns t1
   cross join sys.columns t2
), TheDays as (
   select dateadd(day,N,@date) newDate
     from tally
    where datepart(weekday,dateadd(day,N,@date)) = @dayofweek
)
select max(newDate)
  from TheDays;
```